# Getting random html elements in Development Tools affecting CSS styling

Tags: php, html, css, function

I have a PHP function which contains the footer applied to each of my web pages. For the majority of the pages it is displayed as it should. But on some pages it isn't and it seems to be caused by what I can only describe as 'phantom elements' as they aren't within my HTML/PHP code but are shown in Elements of the browser Development Tools. See the below screenshot of the code:

[Screenshot of code issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoV9R.png)

Basically it adds an empty anchor element which contains no text but CSS is applied to it giving it the padding of the other  tags, which ultimately pushes all of the other list and anchor elements to the right of the empty anchor.

The PHP function is:

```
function enterFooter (){
$pageFoot = <<<FOOT
<footer class="web-foot">
    <div class="link-container">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Homepage</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Sitemap</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Company</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</footer>
FOOT;
echo $pageFooter;
```

Any ideas what could be causing this problem?

Comment: Well I do know it will be something code related, but I can't figure out why it only happens on certain pages when its the same piece of code.

Comment: Probably because something about the code or the context it is in is now the same. You need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: I have added the php code above

Comment: Your sample is valid (except the missed "}" in the end of function and the fact that you use a variable to display static HTML). Are you sure that you show us the exact code you have on your real website?

Comment: Probably on some pages you can have bad html structure (maybe some unclosed tags). Dev tools close unclosed tags automatically but not the way you would like it to. So I don't think it's a problem with footer code.

Comment: Yes this is genuinely the exact code. This function is within a phpfunctions.php file which I have used require_once within each page to call it. Then <?php echo enterFooter(); ?> to call the function to the page. I just don't know where the anchor element can be coming from seeing as it isn't within the function code and is only on certain pages.

Comment: The code presented in this question is not enough to reproduce the issue, it must be something else causing it. Without all the necessary details to reproduce the issue you're unlikely to find a solution here.